# C++ placement new alignment of classes (on a SAMD21 microcontroller)

Tags: c++, memory-management, placement-new, samd21, heap-fragmentation

I am working on an application which is running on a SAMD21 microcontroller. For those unfamiliar with the SAMD21, it contains an ARM Cortex-M0+ processor. The specific model I am using has 32 kB of RAM. My application is running up to the limits of that 32 kB, so I've been working on optimizing the code for memory usage.

One optimization I've been working on is reducing heap fragmentation. For example, I may have a scenario such as the following:

```
A *my_obj = new A();
B *my_second_obj = new B();
delete A;
C *my_third_obj = new C();
```

In the above example, when instantiating `my_third_obj`, the memory allocator may attempt to place it in the empty location that was initially being used by `my_obj`. However, if `my_third_obj` doesn't fit in that spot, then the memory allocator will simply allocate some more space at the top of the heap and move the heap pointer. This will leave a "hole" where `my_obj` was located (which may be filled later by other objects), but this creates heap fragmentation.

In my specific application, I've determined that I will ever only need one active instance of classes A, B, or C at any point in time. Because of this, I was thinking about creating a block of memory which holds the current instance of any of those classes, and simply making the memory block as big as the largest class so that it can hold any of the classes. This would reduce heap fragmentation since there would always be a specific place in memory where I would be allocating these specific classes.

Here's a simple example of what I am thinking:

```
uint32_t max_size = sizeof(A);
max_size = (sizeof(B) > max_size) ? sizeof(B) : max_size;
max_size = (sizeof(C) > max_size) ? sizeof(C) : max_size;
uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[max_size];

//Some time later in the program...
C *my_obj = new(buffer) C();

//Some time later in the program...
my_obj->~C();
my_obj = NULL;
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(max_size));
B *my_other_obj = new(buffer) B();
```

I've never really used **placement new** in previous code that I've written, but I think it would be useful in my current circumstance. My main question here is: given the example that I've laid out, do I need to alter the code in any way to handle alignment issues? Classes A, B, and C all have different member variables and different sizes. Will this code just "work", or do I need to do anything special to handle memory alignment?

Thanks!

Comment: you should probably destroy the C instance properly with `my_obj->~C();` before the memset. Even if it's just plain old data. Also, you should consider using `std::variant<A,B,C>` if it fits your use-case, might help you get rid of some of the boiler-plate

Comment: I wasn't aware of std::variant. It may help with my use case. I'll look more into it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about adding the destructor. I put that into the code example.

Comment: With dynamic memory allocations and placement new, you should care about alignment only if your types are _over-aligned_, which rarely applies in practice (useful for cache-line alignment, SIMD data alignment, etc.). Check the value of [`__STDCPP_DEFAULT_NEW_ALIGNMENT__`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new). Btw, I would allocate a "raw" memory with `operator new` rather than creating an array of `uint8_t`. `std::variant` is a better option, just available not until C++17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I need to alter the code in any way to handle alignment issues?

Yes.

> do I need to do anything special to handle memory alignment?

Yes.

`uint8_t` conceptually represents an unsigned integer with 8 bits. Use `char` or `unsigned char` to represent 1 byte.

Anyway, use `operator new` with size and alignment:

```
auto maxsize = max_of_3(sizeof(A), sizeof(B), sizeof(C)),
auto neededalign = std::align_val_t(max_of_3(alignof(A), alignof(B), alignof(C));
void *buffer = operator new(maxsize, neededalign);
```

or statically:

```
std::aligned_storage<
    max_of_3(sizeof(A), sizeof(B), sizeof(C)),
    max_of_3(alignof(A), alignof(B), alignof(C))> buffer;
A *stuff = new(buffer.data) A;
```

Comment: Thanks! This is a great response. I am torn between accepting this response or accepting the response by Serge Ballista, because both are great responses!

Answer (score 1):

A buffer obtained from malloc is guaranteed to be correctly aligned for any basic type, but I am unsure whether a pointer obtained from `new` is, so I would prefer:

```
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(max_size);   // delete it later with free
```

But you could even get rid of any dynamic allocation by building a custom buffer using `alignas`:

```
// only required for C++11, starting from C++14, std::max is constepr
constexpr size_t max3(size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) {
    uint32_t max_size = i;
    max_size = (i > j) ? i : j;
    max_size = (k > max_size) ? k : max_size;
    return max_size;
}

// declare a custom struct with required size and alignment
struct alignas(max3(alignof(A), alignof(B), alignof(C))) Buffer {
    char buffer[max3(alignof(A), alignof(B), alignof(C))];
};

// build a statically allocated buffer of correct size and alignment
Buffer buffer;
```

From that point on, you can safely inplace construct an object in `buffer` and of course explicitely destroy it before re-using the memory.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent response! I am torn between accepting this response or accepting the response by KamilCuk, because both are very informative.